# SUM is correct for KG but not for Grams in XSL

Tags: xslt

I want to sum up the totals for a column in XSL. It sums up the column for `KG` but it doesn't sum up for `Grams`.

What am I doing wrong that it's not adding up the total for `Grams`?

NB: if the `Grams` column doesn't have any data instead of showing `NA` it must show `(-)`; this part works.

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="MyFormat" NaN=" - " zero-digit="0"/>  // f.h
<xsl:template match="/">
  <table width="100%" border="1">
 <tr>
      <td colspan="12" bgcolor="#66FFCC"><div align="center"><strong> Totals</strong></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td width="5%"><div align="center"><strong>Mass (kg)</strong></div></td>
 <td width="5%"><div align="center"><strong>Grams</strong></div></td>
</tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="Rowsets/Rowset/Row/DATE_WEIGHED">
      <tr>
      <td><div align="center"><xsl:value-of select="../KG"/></div></td>
      <td><div align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(../Grams,'#,###','MyFormat')/></div></td>

   </tr> 
  </xsl:for-each>
   <td bgcolor="#FFCC99"><div align="center"><strong><xsl:value-of select="sum(Rowsets/Rowset/Row/KG)"/></strong></div></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFCC99"><div align="center"><strong><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(Rowsets/Rowset/Row/Grams),'#,###','MyFormat')"/></strong></div></td>
  </tr>
  
  </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please provide a **reproducible** example, including the input - see: [mcve]

Comment: i figured it out thanks

Comment: How it is related to SAP?